# Hibernate Tools for Eclipse Helios

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am new to hibernate. 
I need Hibernate Tools for Eclipse Helios. 
I don't prefer to update directly in online. So downloaded the zip from http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_2_GA.html

In eclipse:
(1) When I tried to install through the zip (containing all JBOSS tools), I got strucked up at 46% in eclipse.. Its not processing further.
(2) When I tried to install the zip which is only for hibernate Tools (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossTools/JBossTools3.2.x/jbosstools-3.2.1.Final.component--hibernatetools-Update-2011-08-01_12-53-33-H1305.zip/download), I got an error during installation..

Can anyone say what is the correct way to install and If I need only Hibernate tools for eclipse, what are the items to be installed from the complete JBoss tools plugin zip?

Comment: why not using the update? (you can check the configuration manager to see which plugin parts don't work and why. There you can check if there are some dependency issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem getting JBoss Tools to install.
There are some conflicting packages which you need to uninstall should you want to install the entire JBoss Tools package.

If all you want to use it for is Hibernate, use the install site and only select the hibernate tools. This should work without any conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks... I need only hibernate tools.. Can I use the zip provided in http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_2_GA.html under the name "Hibernate wizards, query editor, reverse engineering & more".. Since I have some network issues, I cant update directly from the site. Is the above zip is sufficient, or do I need to use some other files?